# Mismatch between String Date and NSDate through dateFromString in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, string, nsdate

I am having an issue with converting a string to NSDate in Xcode: I am trying to get the current date, subtract one day and set the hour to noon. This is how I'm going about it (thw two snippets are in different functions):

```
let date = NSDate();
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //var locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    //dateFormatter.locale = locale
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    var string = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    var localdate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)
    var localString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(localdate!)
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: localdate!)
    self.dateCriteriaHour = components.hour
    self.dateCriteriaDay = components.day
    self.dateCriteriaMonth = components.month
    self.dateCriteriaYear = components.year
```

This seems to work: I get the current date's components. Then I do this:

```
var day = String(self.dateCriteriaDay - 1)
                var month = String(currentMonth)
                var year = String(self.dateCriteriaYear)
                var hour = "12:00"
                var date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " " + hour
                var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/m/dd HH:mm"
                var criteriaDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)

                println(date)
                println(NSDate())
                println(criteriaDate)
```

This is where things get strange. Here is the output to the console:

```
2015/7/11 12:00
2015-07-12 15:21:42 +0000
Optional(2015-01-11 04:00:00 +0000)
```

I understand that the device stores time in its selected time zone so I'm not too worried about that. What puzzles me is basically that everything is right except for the month, even though it comes out right in the string.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dateformat is wrong.

```
dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm
   ^^         ^^
```

You use `mm` two times. A lower case `m` means minutes, an upper case `M` means month. So your dateFormat should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: See the relevant [docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) - `MM` or `M` for the month.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot guys.